# Sequelize Associations Multiple Foreign Keys from Same Table

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

### Goal

Using Sequelize and Postgres, I am trying to create a Readings table which contains values and their units. The units are foreign keys to another table, Units. I am confused with the associations.

#### Assumptions

Each Reading must have a sun value/unit and a moon value/unit. 
The reading units can be different

### Example Database

```
Readings
id | sun_temp | sun_temp_unit_id | moon_temp | moon_temp_unit_id
1      5               1               2             2
2      10              1               4             2

Units
id | Name
1    brapple
2    schmeckle
```

### Readings Table Definition

```
const Reading = sequelize.define("Reading", {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    sun_temp: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    moon_temp: DataTypes.INTEGER
}, {
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: "readings"
});

Reading.associate = (models) => {
    Reading.belongsTo(models.Unit, {foreignKey: {name: 'sun_temp_unit_id'})
    Reading.belongsTo(models.Unit, {foreignKey: {name: 'moon_temp_unit_id'})
}
```

#### Units Table Definition

```
const Unit = sequelize.define("Unit", {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: DataTypes.STRING
}, {
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: "units"
});

Unit.associate = (models) => {
    ??
}
```

#### Questions:

1. What type of an associate is this?
2. How do I set up the Reading model?
3. How do I set up the Unit model?
4. What query is used to get the Reading Model and the Units models? (Here I would like to see/access each Units name for reading value/unit pair)
5. If this is a poor way to set up the database, what are other suggestions?